# Running a uWSGI app that uses uwsgidecorators from shell python directly

Tags: flask, uwsgi, pythoninterpreter

As you may know, `uwsgidecorators` are only working if your app is running in the context of `uwsgi`, which is not exactly clear from the documentation: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html

My code is using these decorators, for example for locking:

```
@uwsgidecorators.lock
def critical_func():
  ...
```

And this works just fine when I deploy my app with uwsgi, however, when starting it directly from Python shell, I'm getting an expected error:

```
File ".../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/uwsgidecorators.py", line 10, in <module>
  import uwsgi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uwsgi'
```

Is there any known solution to run my app in both modes? obviously I don't need the synchronization and other capabilities to work when using simple interpreter, but doing some try-except importing seems like really bad coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the meantime I did the following implementation, would be happy to know there's something simpler:

```
class _dummy_lock():
    """Implement the uwsgi lock decorator without actually doing any locking"""
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)


class uwsgi_lock():
    """
    This is a lock decorator that wraps the uwsgi decorator to allow it to work outside of a uwsgi environment as well.
    ONLY STATIC METHODS can be locked using this functionality
    """
    def __init__(self, f):
        try:
            import uwsgidecorators
            self.lock = uwsgidecorators.lock(f)  # the real uwsgi lock class
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            self.lock = _dummy_lock(f)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.lock(*args, **kwargs)

@staticmethod
@uwsgi_lock
def critical_func():
  ...
```